# Problems in achieving inter thread communication.

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am trying to learn threads in java, and got this idea of implementing a coin phone functionality using threads.

I am able to write down the basic tasks. My Flow chart is as below.

[image]

I have tried writing a class for checking hook status.

```
public class Hook {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Hook.class.getName());


OffTheHook offTheHook= new OffTheHook();


void checkHook(Boolean hookStatus, String keyPressed){
    log.debug("Hook Status "+hookStatus);
    if(hookStatus==true){
        offTheHook.beforeDroppingCoin(hookStatus);
    }else{
        if(keyPressed!=null){
            DisplayMessages.displayMessage("FollowInstruction");


        }else{
            displayReadyMessage();
        }
    }
}

public static void displayReadyMessage(){
    DisplayMessages.displayMessage("ready");        
}
}
```

Another timer class..

```
public class TimerClass extends Thread{
int timeInMilli;
boolean status=false;

public TimerClass(int timeInMilli){
    this.timeInMilli=timeInMilli;

}

@Override
public void run() { 
    timer();
}

private void timer(){
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(timeInMilli);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

How do I make these classes communicate with each other(small example will be enough). Moreover my requirement is if the headset is back on the hook the call must get cut.. How should I write the code to monitor that status? based  on that status I need to make decision. At the same time I need to have another Thread that shall input status of hooks.

A small snippet of code will be that does the similar functionality, will be of great help.

Comment: Your code would be a lot more readable if you learn some common conventions.  For one thing, objects in your program should represent _things_ and their class names should be nouns.  Also, methods _do_ things;  their names should be verb phrases that say what they do.  It is not at all clear to the reader what an `OffTheHook` object represents, nor what it's method, `beforeDroppingCoin()` does to it.

Comment: Your method, `checkHook()` is deceptively named.  It doesn't check the hook status.  It looks like it's designed to be called by some other method that already has checked the status.  That method passes the status into `checkHook()`, and `checkHook()` does something about it.

Comment: Re, "I am trying to learn threads in java."  IMO, it's too soon for that.  You could learn a lot about the Java language and about programming in general before you try to learn about threads.  What's more:  It's not at all clear to me how using threads in your phone simulation would improve it.  The time to use threads is either (a) when your program needs to perform lengthy computations in the background, or (b) when it needs to respond to different sources of input (events) that are not synchronized with one another.

Comment: @jameslarge. on hook status, Basically an input thread must read the data from the user and then put pass it to the hook status.

Comment: @jameslarge. Why Threads? there are few things which needs to be performed simultaneously. Like checking hook status, Counters and their status. If in need to get the hook status it should be from a thread. So that it can be as close to reality.

Comment: Depends on where you obtain the hook status.  You are programming a _simulation_, not an actual telephone.  If the events driving the simulation all come from a GUI, then that's _one_ source of events.  Likewise, if they all come from a script.  In an actual, physical telephone, merely _getting_ the hook status is accomplished by reading from an I/O port or a memory-mapped location.  Reacting to a _change_ in hook status could well happen in a single-threaded, top-level _event loop_ that _polls_ the hook, and other input sources.

Comment: @jameslarge, I am planning to input that from the console..

Comment: OK, so one thread to read inputs from the console and it changes the state of the simulation in response to those inputs.  If you want to have "timeout" events, that could be a second thread, but you could simplify the program by using standard library `Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` objects.  Technically, using those classes _is_ multi-threading, but it's a significant step down in complexity as compared to creating your own threads.